# jQuery Isotope / Masonary Gutter Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am using jQuery [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). It's a great plugin but I'm having a little issue with aligning the items in masonry mode. My container is 960px wide and my goal is to get 4 items to line up perfectly as if it were using the 960px grid system. So, both the left and right edges would be touching the the edge of the container. Here is a screen shot of how it looks at the moment:

[image]

My code is currently like so:

**JS:**

```
$('#container').isotope({
  itemSelector : '.item',
      masonry : {
          columnWidth : 240,
          gutterWidth: 10
      }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.item{
width:230px;
background:red;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="item">a</div>
```

So far the only way I have managed to get it to work is to set the width to `240px` but then there is no gap between the items.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle showing what I have http://jsfiddle.net/qGJhe/

Comment: Do your columns touch the edges of your container without using isotope (just using float)?

Comment: no, currently I dont have any grid or css on it. other than above. If it wasn't dynamically generated i'd just adjust the margin on the last one but I can't do that. What I want is for 3 columns to nicely take up the space of 960px

Comment: Would be better if you recreate the page in jsFiddle since it would make it easier for us to debug it :)

Comment: ok, I will get that done asap.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGJhe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qGJhe/), I added background color for the container to check the extra gap that you're having issue with but it shows no extra gap.

Also, it doesn't honor your 960px width as the layout is responsive. So it seems to me that you didn't copy exactly the same codes (html, css, jQuery) that you have on your actual page.

Anyway, I disabled the responsive code bit to make it honor the fixed 960px width and saw that extra gap of 10px. http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/qGJhe/3/

That made me realised that your calculation for the gutter size as well as the width of the element are rather inaccurate.

**Element width of 240px will not give you space for gutter at all.** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/qGJhe/4/

> `gutterSize = (containerWidth - (elementWidth * numberOfElement) / numberOfGutters)`
>
> **`gutterSize = (960 - (240 * 4) ) / 3) = 0`**
>
> `totalWidth = (elementWidth * numberOfElement) + (gutterSize * numberOfGutters)`
>
> `totalWidth = (240 * 4) + (3 * 0) = 960`
>
> `extraGap = containerWidth - totalWidth`
>
> **`extraGap = 960 - 960 = 0`**

**Element width of 230px plus gutter size of 13 will give you 1px of extra gap** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/qGJhe/5/

> `gutterSize = (containerWidth - (elementWidth * numberOfElement) / numberOfGutters)`
>
> **`gutterSize = (960 - (230 * 4) ) / 3) = 13.33 = 13 (rounded)`**
>
> `totalWidth = (elementWidth * numberOfElement) + (gutterSize * numberOfGutters)`
>
> `totalWidth = (230 * 4) + (3 * 13) = 959`
>
> `extraGap = containerWidth - totalWidth`
>
> **`extraGap = 960 - 959 = 1`**

If you want to have 4 elements in a row to fit in nicely within 960px, then you'd need to reduce the width of the element to 225px and have gutter size of 20px.

**Element width of 225px plus gutter size of 20 will be perfect!** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/qGJhe/6/

> `gutterSize = (containerWidth - (elementWidth * numberOfElement) / numberOfGutters)`
>
> **`gutterSize = (960 - (225 * 4) ) / 3) = 20`**
>
> `totalWidth = (elementWidth * numberOfElement) + (gutterSize * numberOfGutters)`
>
> `totalWidth = (225 * 4) + (3 * 20) = 960`
>
> `extraGap = containerWidth - totalWidth`
>
> **`extraGap = 960 - 960 = 0`**

Comment: Thx! Your calculation helped me :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the modified layout mode?

Using `gutterWidth` isn't a standard option. The [docs say](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#modified_layout_modes) that you need to add the code from the source of the demo page.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-gutters.html

```
// modified Isotope methods for gutters in masonry
$.Isotope.prototype._getMasonryGutterColumns = function() {
  var gutter = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.gutterWidth || 0;
      containerWidth = this.element.width();

  this.masonry.columnWidth = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||
                // or use the size of the first item
                this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
                // if there's no items, use size of container
                containerWidth;

  this.masonry.columnWidth += gutter;

  this.masonry.cols = Math.floor( ( containerWidth + gutter ) / this.masonry.columnWidth );
  this.masonry.cols = Math.max( this.masonry.cols, 1 );
};
```

Comment: I did this and it began to work for me, so thank you! The docs do mention it but if you skipped the demos you will not realise! Make sure your measurements are right too obviously and you should arrive at the result.

Comment: That also worked for me. I was not going to try this fix but surprised and happy it works. This should be the accepted answer - voting up.

Comment: will it work for perfect masonry extension ?? i've tried but not working.. :(